# How to Add Stacktrace or debug Option when Building Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio, stack-trace

I was trying to investigate the project build error in the console output as follow:

```
:myapp:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
...
...

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I suspect it has something to do with resource not found error. My question is, at IDE level how can I add `--stacktrace` or `--debug` option so that it can produce more information for me to debug?

Answer (score 251, accepted):

You can use GUI to add these gradle command line flags from

```
File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler
```

For MacOS user, it's here

```
Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler
```

like this (add `--stacktrace` or `--debug`)

[image]

Note that the screenshot is from before 0.8.10, the option is *no longer* in the `Compiler > Gradle` section, it's now in a separate section named `Compiler (Gradle-based Android Project)`

Comment: This is gone in 0.8.12. Anyone know more?

Comment: They took Compiler option on root I think, checked in Android Studio 0.8.10. Now studio calling it Compiler (Gradle-based Android Project). Check once and update.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but I am talking about something else. In the Gradle section of the "Project Settings" they have removed the "Command-line Options" field. So there's no place to add flags to Gradle. (The "VM Options" field is still there, though.)

Comment: @nmr: Do not refer to "Gradle." Instead, check the "Compiler (Gradle-based Android Projects)". There you will find the "Comand-line Options."

Comment: In Android Studio 1.2.2 (on Windows) it's `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler` where you can add the flags in `Command-line Options:`.

Comment: In Android Studio 1.5.1 (on Mac) it's now `Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler`

Comment: In Android Studio 2.2.3, (on Windows) it is still Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler.

Comment: Latest documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#gradle-console

Comment: found it on 3.2.1

Comment: if this is not working try https://stackoverflow.com/a/65132651/10505343

Answer (score 40):

On the `Mac` version of `Android Studio Beta 1.2`, it's under

`Android Studio->preferences->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler`

Comment: This answer is correct as of Android Studio 2.0 as well.

Comment: In the latest versions of AS (2.2 and 2.3) to see Compiler option you need to be out of open project, go to AS begin  (where the recent project are visible) and click Configure -> Preferences->Build, Execution,Deployment. Otherwise Compiler is not visible

Answer (score 34):

What I use for debugging purposes is running the gradle task with stacktrace directly in terminal. Then you don't affect your normal compiles.

**From your project root directory, via terminal you can use:**

```
./gradlew assembleMyBuild --stacktrace
```

Comment: Tip for WINDOWS users if the terminal not working simply click ctrl twice(a popup window of run appears) and paste the above there.

Answer (score 26):

In Android Studios 2.1.1,  the command-line Options is under "Build, Execution, Deployment">"Compiler"

[image]

Comment: also you can add --scan

Answer (score 9):

To add a stacktrace click on the Gradle on the right side of Android project screen;

1. Click on the settings icon;
   this will open the settings page,
2. Then click on compiler
3. Then add the command `--stacktrace` or `--debug` as shown;

   [image]
4. Run the application again to get the gradle report.

Comment: What if these options are ignored? Shall we clear some cache?

Answer (score 6):

(edited Dec 2018: Android Studio 3.2.1 on Mac too)

For Android Studio 3.1.3 on a Mac, it was under

> Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler

and then, to view the stack trace, press this button

[image: button to show stack trace]

Comment: I followed the steps given in the solutions below, but I still get the prompt -" Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights."

Comment: @Nishita , did you type in `--stacktrace` and/or `--info` and/or `--debug` and/or `--scan` under command-line options?

Comment: yes I did. Enabling it in preferences settings did not help. I had to manually run the command on terminal to see the stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

For Android Studio 3.1.3 it was under

> File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler

Answer (score 1):

my solution is this:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you use fastlane, additional flags can be passed with

```
gradle(
   ...
   flags: "{your flags}"
)
```

More information [here](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/gradle/)

Answer (score 0):

my solution is this:

```
cd android
```

and then:

```
./gradlew assembleMyBuild --stacktrace
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into your project.

install Gradle.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html

On a mac: `brew install gradle`

Then `gradle build --stacktrace`

Answer (score -1):

To Increase Maximum heap: Click to open your Android Studio, look at below pictures. Step by step. ANDROID STUDIO v2.1.2

Click to navigate to Settings from the Configure or GO TO FILE SETTINGS at the top of Android Studio.

[image]

check also the android compilers from the link to confirm if it also change if not increase to the same size you modify from the compiler link.

Note: You can increase the size base on your memory capacity and remember this setting is base on Android Studio v2.1.2

Comment: Is this the right question to this answer? it seems like it belongs elsewhere.

Answer (score -4):

bro it is very easy
download an apk file of any game from browser and double click it whet it open than your pc would have the capability to make any apk file and then try it. solution got after 1 year

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).