# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > ProcessException: or 'VirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

When I try to run my app I get this Error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

if I try use jdk1.7

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

thanks for help

Comment: It seems like you're compiling more than once the same library and there is a package conflict.

Comment: [The answer to this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674091/how-to-add-stacktrace-or-debug-option-when-building-android-studio-project) shows you how to get more information out of the build to explain what went wrong. The current output isn't very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html). But you can use [retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) for lambda.