# What is wrong with this? running a desktop libgdx app

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

So I am trying to run a desktop libgdx project from android studio. But I am getting this.

```
12:52:42 AM: Executing external task 'desktop:run'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Project directory '' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.074 secs
Project directory '' does not exist.
12:52:42 AM: External task execution finished 'desktop:run'.
```

Anyone knows what went wrong and what I can do about this to get it run?

Comment: So did you run it with --stacktrace --info and --debug? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674091/how-to-add-stacktrace-or-debug-option-when-building-android-studio-project

Comment: I just tried it and put --stacktrace --debug in the command line options and hit apply. However, it didn't run anything for me to trace.  What am I suppose to do next?

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with a faulty run configuration? Did you follow the steps [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA#running-your-project)?