# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebugcom.android.build.api.transform.TransformException

Tags: android, android-multidex

i am wroking on a app where am share content on sacial media but now i faced a problem like i spend 2-3 day for this error that why i am posting this question please help me

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\Amit Basliyal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23-1' (Expected 'C:\Users\Amit Basliyal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23')
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 14.241 secs
Information:3 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

and 
 **my gradle is**

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


  android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    jumboMode true
    incremental true
    dexInProcess false
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    preDexLibraries = false
   }

 }
  dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.2'
 }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and

**build gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

 buildscript {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
   }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
  }

 allprojects {
    repositories {
      jcenter()
    }
 }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Anyways, please show the full Gradle output, not just the final error

Comment: @cricket_007 see now

Comment: Hmm, nothing really sticks out of that build other than the first message. 1) Are there any JAR files in the libs folder? 2) You can remove `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'` from your dependencies

Comment: i remove dipendency and  jar file is their volley but not working

Comment: Why do you need Volley, Okhttp, and the Apache HTTP? If you do need Volley, use the Gradle dependency for it as well

Comment: what is dependency for volley

Comment: The version may be updated, but I have `com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0`

Comment: same problem @cricket_007 after that

Comment: Try to see if you can get a more descriptive error.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37266244/2308683