# Execution failed for task ':dndgridview:processDebugResources'

Tags: android

How to solve "com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt" error?

Comment: The solution would be easier to give with more information about the Gradle error.

Comment: bling guess(as there is no enough information in the question itself): change compileSdkVersion to fit the support library version(or used resources like material styles)

Comment: Try this, and edit your question accordingly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674091/how-to-add-stacktrace-or-debug-option-when-building-android-studio-project

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Comment: post `build.gradle` file and error log too

Comment: change in build.gradle issue solved Thanks