# Can't read package name from manifest

Tags: android

This happen when I rebuild, Below is the error, I don't know how to fix it:

```
Error:15:11:37.950 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    15:11:37.951 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    15:11:37.951 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    15:11:37.951 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
    15:11:37.951 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\Dell\AndroidStudioProjects\LearnAdvent\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
    15:11:37.951 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    15:11:37.951 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
    15:11:37.951 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
```

My package name declare in manifest, I'd tried to clean then rebuild, but still doesn't work.

note: the package name in manifest same with applicationID in build.gradle

Comment: What do you mean you cannot read the package name? In the code i cannot see you reading package name any where?

Comment: i can ofc, the error said like that :Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\Dell\AndroidStudioProjects\LearnAdvent\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: ohh.. did you try to clean the project and rebuild it?

Comment: yes, but its not working bro... as u see the package name, i dont change and still the same since i start.

Comment: when did it start happening first time? What action did you perform with your build?

Comment: let me know one thing is the application id in gradle file and package name in manifest are same?

Comment: 2. yes bro, its same... before i can run or debug my app... just this afternoon, its cant be.

Comment: 1. this is login activity

Comment: try copying the `AndroidManifest.xml` to a new file and use replace the original file with it. Sometimes windows will messing your project file. And try to not place your project file in `drive C:`. Move it to somewhere else.

Comment: Get more error output. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674091/how-to-add-stacktrace-or-debug-option-when-building-android-studio-project

Comment: Can you show the full gradle file? As far as I know, `applicationId` actually overrides what's defined in the XML anyway

Comment: i update it already bro, the build gradle above

Comment: Did one of the answers below help you? If yes, please consider accepting it ...

Answer (score 0):

I have never done Android development; however, I'd like to give the following hints:

1. I currently can't see the package name in your manifest, so this might be the problem (in your version from some minutes ago, before you have edited your question, the package name was in the manifest).
2. If the package name *is* in the manifest and the error persists, then it might help to re-read and think about the error message. It says it can't read the package name from `C:\Users\Dell\AndroidStudioProjects\LearnAdvent\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`.

This could have the following reasons:

- The manifest might not be at the place where Android looks for it. So double check that your manifest really is in the folder `C:\Users\Dell\AndroidStudioProjects\LearnAdvent\app\src\main` and that it is really named `AndroidManifest.xml`.
- There might be problems with the access permissions. Double check if the file and folder permissions allow you to do any operation which is needed with the folder `C:\Users\Dell\AndroidStudioProjects\LearnAdvent\app\src\main` as well with the file `AndroidManifest.xml`.
- An application might have locked that manifest file so that your development tools can't access it. This could happen if an application (possibly one of the development tools) did not close cleanly when you ended it or when it has done its work. So restarting your PC might help. Alternatively, you could try to identify and end processes which lock that file using appropriate tools. Since we should not recommend tools here, you could search on superuser.com for them.

Comment: Package was always in the manifest. Question had bad formatting

Comment: yup, packagae was always in manifest. then ive been searching for 4 hours where the hell the bad formatting and i still cant find it, haha. T_T