# Exception parsing classes in android at runtime in android studio

Tags: java, android, exception

I am getting this error while running the application on device.
The error is stated below:

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process.

Comment: Well, if classes can't be parsed, it sounds like a syntax error. Check your code carefully and create a [mcve] here if you really want help

Comment: Thanks for your instant reply..But i am able compile the project properly.so no issues in it .But while running the application this error is been trigger.If possible help with other solution

Comment: Compile it how? That's a Gradle error thrown around the time of compilation...

Comment: Build project doesnot show the given error ..only when click on run its shows the error

Comment: Add more of the error, please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674091/how-to-add-stacktrace-or-debug-option-when-building-android-studio-project

Comment: Added the given code   dexOptions {
incremental true
javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}  in build.gradle.This helped to find the location of error where the path doesnot match and solved the issue ..Thanks