# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForProductionRelease'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-proguard, signed-apk

I am trying to generate signed apk but unfortunately receiving below error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForProductionRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

Full log wih --debug

```
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:cardview-v7.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:appcompat-v7.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:support-v4.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:support-v13.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/support-v13/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/support-v13/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:design.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/design/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/design/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/github/ParkSangGwon/TedPicker/v1.0.10/TedPicker-v1.0.10.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/github/ParkSangGwon/TedPicker/v1.0.10/TedPicker-v1.0.10.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/2.6.8/crashlytics-2.6.8.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/2.6.8/crashlytics-2.6.8.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.commonsware.cwac:camera.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/beta/1.2.5/beta-1.2.5.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/beta/1.2.5/beta-1.2.5.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/io/fabric/sdk/android/fabric/1.3.17/fabric-1.3.17.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/io/fabric/sdk/android/fabric/1.3.17/fabric-1.3.17.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics-core/2.3.17/crashlytics-core-2.3.17.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics-core/2.3.17/crashlytics-core-2.3.17.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/answers/1.3.13/answers-1.3.13.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/answers/1.3.13/answers-1.3.13.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:cardview-v7.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:appcompat-v7.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:support-v4.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:support-v13.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/support-v13/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/support-v13/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:design.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/design/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/design/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/github/ParkSangGwon/TedPicker/v1.0.10/TedPicker-v1.0.10.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/github/ParkSangGwon/TedPicker/v1.0.10/TedPicker-v1.0.10.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/2.6.8/crashlytics-2.6.8.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/2.6.8/crashlytics-2.6.8.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.commonsware.cwac:camera.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/beta/1.2.5/beta-1.2.5.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/beta/1.2.5/beta-1.2.5.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/io/fabric/sdk/android/fabric/1.3.17/fabric-1.3.17.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/io/fabric/sdk/android/fabric/1.3.17/fabric-1.3.17.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics-core/2.3.17/crashlytics-core-2.3.17.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics-core/2.3.17/crashlytics-core-2.3.17.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/answers/1.3.13/answers-1.3.13.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/answers/1.3.13/answers-1.3.13.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:cardview-v7.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:appcompat-v7.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:support-v4.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:support-v13.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/support-v13/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/support-v13/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:design.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/design/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/design/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/github/ParkSangGwon/TedPicker/v1.0.10/TedPicker-v1.0.10.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/github/ParkSangGwon/TedPicker/v1.0.10/TedPicker-v1.0.10.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/2.6.8/crashlytics-2.6.8.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/2.6.8/crashlytics-2.6.8.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.commonsware.cwac:camera.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/beta/1.2.5/beta-1.2.5.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/beta/1.2.5/beta-1.2.5.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/io/fabric/sdk/android/fabric/1.3.17/fabric-1.3.17.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/io/fabric/sdk/android/fabric/1.3.17/fabric-1.3.17.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics-core/2.3.17/crashlytics-core-2.3.17.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics-core/2.3.17/crashlytics-core-2.3.17.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/answers/1.3.13/answers-1.3.13.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/answers/1.3.13/answers-1.3.13.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:cardview-v7.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:appcompat-v7.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:support-v4.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:support-v13.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/support-v13/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/support-v13/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:design.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/design/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/android/support/design/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/github/ParkSangGwon/TedPicker/v1.0.10/TedPicker-v1.0.10.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/github/ParkSangGwon/TedPicker/v1.0.10/TedPicker-v1.0.10.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/2.6.8/crashlytics-2.6.8.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/2.6.8/crashlytics-2.6.8.pom'.
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)
```

I can see few warnings but no errors except above one. Are warnings equivalent to errors in this case?
Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: What details do the logs show you?

Comment: Messages log shows me warnings only, please see edited question

Comment: Get more output, then. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674091/how-to-add-stacktrace-or-debug-option-when-building-android-studio-project

Comment: I am getting these 2 separated messages now after doing above trick 1. Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details 2. Error:java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first. So, should I add above warnings in proguard files?

Comment: Can you show the full gradle output in the question, please?

Comment: Please see the edits, added full log

Comment: Was that `--stacktrace` with, or without `--debug`?

Comment: With --stacktrace and without --debug

Comment: There should be something displayed somewhere above the top exception that describes what the warnings are

Comment: With --debug, I am getting something like above edits

Comment: Are you trying to build a CommonsWare project? ;) All I can really say is try to provide a [mcve] of your code / full Gradle file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding following line in proguard-rules.pro works for me

```
-ignorewarnings -keep class * { public private *; }
```

Comment: This worked but what does it do? does my classes must not be public or private that causes this err?

Answer (score 0):

you can add this in build.gradle file and rebuild project

```
aaptOptions {  
    cruncherEnabled = false  
}
```