# Invalid color in Android Compilation. How to fix .9.png

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, android-drawable, nine-patch

I'm getting the following error when compiling in Android Studio

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  error: found an invalid color.
```

The image that is causing the error is already a `.9.png` file and it looks like this in Android Studio

[image]
[image]

I am not sure how to solve this. I referred to this two questions

[How can I track down the cause of Android "found an invalid color" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542862/how-can-i-track-down-the-cause-of-android-found-an-invalid-color-error)

[Android : 9-Patch image Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359795/android-9-patch-image-error)

and both indicate that the border around the image should be transparent. I'm guessing I have to fix the "bad patches" shown in red. if that's the case how can I fix them and make the compilation succeed?

Comment: did you fin a solution to this ?

Comment: @Faridomastr yes! I literally made small changes to the file, saved it, reverted those changes, saved again and no more problems. Hope it is the same for you!