# Android X Project

Tags: java, android, androidx

> Failed to transform 'C:\Developer\NftAndroid Files\NftLatest\app\libs\pass-v1.2.2.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: 8. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

What is the reason for this error ?

Comment: As the error is saying "Run with --stacktrace for more details".
What does the stacktrace  is saing? check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674091/how-to-add-stacktrace-or-debug-option-when-building-android-studio-project)

Comment: These might be caused due to use of older versions of some libraries, check and make sure you are using latest versions of each and every one of them.