# how i can fix this errors in android studio kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

that doesn't work anyOne can help me?

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\ABDERRAHIM\Downloads\Compressed\android-studio-ide-202.7188722-windows\TipTime

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\ABDERRAHIM\Downloads\Compressed\android-studio-ide-202.7188722-windows\TipTime\app\build.gradle' line: 5
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method buildFeatures() for arguments [build_edslfr8cpuhvllawup55ot91a$_run_closure1@4bc52b03] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

Answer (score 0):

Could you update with the entire error log here? Try the below command in terminal or refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674091/how-to-add-stacktrace-or-debug-option-when-building-android-studio-project)

```
gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace
```

Also, include the build.gradle file under the App directory.