# How to run with --stracktrace option so that I can run react-native-cli project

Tags: react-native, android-studio, gradle

I have a question about running React-native-cli project. When I ran this command: `npx react-native run-android` , it returned this result:

```
info Installing the app...
> Task :app:generatePackageList FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
1 actionable task: 1 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\IT\React.js\JAMK\e06Movies\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 131

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generatePackageList'.
> argument type mismatch

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\IT\React.js\JAMK\e06Movies\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 131

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generatePackageList'.
> argument type mismatch

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

    at makeError (D:\IT\React.js\JAMK\e06Movies\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at D:\IT\React.js\JAMK\e06Movies\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (D:\IT\React.js\JAMK\e06Movies\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (D:\IT\React.js\JAMK\e06Movies\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I have added --stacktrace in Android Studio by this instruction: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674091/how-to-add-stacktrace-or-debug-option-when-building-android-studio-project" but it didn't work at all.
[image]
Can someone suggest to me some solutions for this problem? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

npx react-native run-android --verbose

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have tried but it still returns the similar error