# Android Studio build time

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

When I try to build my project with Android Studio, after saying build successfully as in the image, It does not go to the install part for about 5 minutes. But after disconnecting the entire network, the build ends in seconds as in the image and goes to the install part. When I try it in gradle offline mode, It is completed in 5 minutes. I think it's a dependency issue with the network, but I couldn't find anything absurd in the dependencies either. By the way, I am not using a proxy.

[image: Build Image]

[image: Dependencies]

Comment: Have you looked at verbose debugging? You can identify which dependency download is taking more time.

Comment: Check this answer. Use `--stacktrace` to debug in verbose mode

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21674403/4491971