# Unable to build project. Can't find same error in googling

Tags: android, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform artifact 'activity.aar (androidx.activity:activity:1.6.0-beta01)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-manifest}
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\ADMIN.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.activity\activity\1.6.0-beta01\d888a4569f3c67638afc7aa0d778acd7f41cedb5\activity-1.6.0-beta01.aar.
> > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\ADMIN.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.activity\activity\1.6.0-beta01\d888a4569f3c67638afc7aa0d778acd7f41cedb5\activity-1.6.0-beta01.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
> Failed to transform artifact 'activity.aar (androidx.activity:activity:1.6.0-beta01)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-manifest}
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\ADMIN.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.activity\activity\1.6.0-beta01\d888a4569f3c67638afc7aa0d778acd7f41cedb5\activity-1.6.0-beta01.aar.
> > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\ADMIN.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.activity\activity\1.6.0-beta01\d888a4569f3c67638afc7aa0d778acd7f41cedb5\activity-1.6.0-beta01.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

Comment: please give us the detail from the log by running it with stacktrace as the suggested from the prompt

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by upgrading to the latest Gradle and compile version.

In Android/build.gradle
Update

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'

dependencies{
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
}
```

In app/build.gradle

Update

```
compileSdkVersion 33
```

In gradle.wrapper.properties, update

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```

Comment: I got the issue after upgrading flutter. This solution fixed the issue.

Comment: This answer solved my Failed to transform activity issue

Answer (score -1):

When you get an error like this it's hard to pinpoint what the issue is, but it provides a clue at the end (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

You can do so using the command below or several different ways explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674091/how-to-add-stacktrace-or-debug-option-when-building-android-studio-project)

```
./gradlew assembleMyBuild --stacktrace
```

Give it a try and post the actual error that's preventing the build.

Comment: could you argument what isn't an answer in my post, according to this link, this qualifies as an answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297066/meta-meta-stack-overflow-when-should-i-answer-or-comment

Comment: deleted my comment. thank you for your input to me. @david-a